# What if I get born again as the same person for ever?

Tags: consciousness, solipsism

What if after I die my life starts all over again? With the same body and the same consciousness! Do you have counterarguments?

Comment: Then you would ask the same questions over and over.

Comment: Somewhere between 18 hours ago and 2 days ago something pretty nasty appears to have happened to you. However, your recovery  seems well underway! Hope you're not too bored!

Comment: Hi Bee Berry, are you okay? Judging by this and the other similar questions which you have recently posted, I can see that you are really struggling with the idea of solipsism (that of you being the only person in existence) and it has me worried. If it means anything, I can say with absolute certainty that that is not the case. But I really think that you should talk to someone about this. We're here for you. :)

Comment: No i am not ok 

Comment: Vote to close; is speculative.

Comment: The counterargument for afterlife largely consists of a lack of [empirical evidence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empirical_evidence) for consciousness persisting after death. To date, no scientific validation of such claims has occurred. Anyone can construct sentences about the universe. Proving them is an entirely different matter.

Comment: If you're searching for meaning in the face of scientific fact, you might want to consider Camus. https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/21342/why-and-how-is-camus-against-nihilism

Comment: I'm so sorry that you're struggling. If you'd like we can talk in chat. I have to go right now, but maybe in about two hours?

Comment: Is the source of your pain in the dislike of (1) your current body and or mind; (2) your current circumstances; (3) possibly losing the fruits of your efforts; or (4) something else?

Comment: Mark Morales do you have Instagram or discord or telegram?

Comment: I do have Instagram, but I don't have my phone on me right now. Do you have Facebook or Twitter?

Comment: My IG is: Kdjddjwj

Comment: "What if after I die my life starts all over again?" What if X? What if Y? What if [insert *any* hypothetical potential possibility here] ? My question to you is: what is your point?

Comment: I searched Kdjddjwj on Instagram and didn't get any results. Did you mistype your username?

Comment: My new username is: cindyx68

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/82184/is-reincarnation-inevitable/82192#82192

Comment: One argument against cyclical time (which includes your question) is its redundancy and lack of meaning in the first place. Universe going over and over exactly the same thing robs "going" of any purpose and meaning and makes similar to "not going anywhere". Doing redundant things by the very definition of "redundant" (= not needed in any way) is similar waste. These are arguments against cyclical time (which includes your question)

Answer (score 3):

The problem with such a scenario is this: It is entirely unclear what it *means* to say that someone "lives their life over again".

Answer (score 1):

In the science fiction novel [Timequake by Kurt Vonnegut](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001QNVP7C) the entire universe repeats the 10 years from 1991 to 2001. Every event repeats precisely. Everybody knows exactly what is going to happen and is unable to do anything different from what happened the first time.

Vonnegut makes many interesting observations, some of which are very funny and some are quite depressing. But one question he raises is, what exactly is the difference for most people? Most people are just going along. They make very little difference in their own lives. Like being in a canoe and moving the paddle backward at exactly the rate the water is moving, neither slowing the boat nor speeding it up.  The 10 years were like that. Everybody simple went along with it because they had no choice.

Arguments against this are certainly possible. All you have to do is something beyond neutral paddling. Look around and see what a nice day it is. Dip your hand in the water and marvel how cold it is and that you can feel it. Splash a little water up and see how the dros sparkle in the sun. Paddle over to the shore and have a look at that interesting rock. Find a pretty beach and get out and have a rest in the sun.

Until the end of the 10-year timequake. Then suddenly your free will is back and you don't remember what is going to happen. And neither does anybody else.

Comment: I was wondering what was going on back then!

Answer (score 1):

> What if after I die my life starts all over again? With the same body and the same consciousness! Do you have counterarguments?

Body and consciousness are starting points. But life is about experiences. You will have different experiences (different parents, friends, education..) it will be a completely different life and you will be a different person.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that be great? And it's gonna happen. Gods created the perfect universe for it. There is an infinity of big bangs following each other up in serially.

Every new universe has its own beginning in time. The clone argument doesn't hold for separate universes. Every time fresh matter particle are sprayed into existence, on two sides of a 4D wormhole, sticking to 3D only. And every time a new you comes into being. But in different circumstances.

Comment: ...Yeah, don't listen to this person, Bee.

Comment: @MarkMorales He asked for it...

Comment: Take a look at some of Bee's other posts. I don't think that they're trolling us. It looks like they're going through some sort of existential crisis. So let's be careful with what we say to them.

Comment: @MarkMoralesII yes, I get you. That'swhy I said it can be always a different life.

Comment: But that's still trolling them.

Comment: @MarkMoralesII Why is that trolling? She asked what would happen if she was born as himself over and over. I told him not to worry, as you are not born the same over and over. Every time you are reborn, it will be a different story as the previous life.

Comment: She asked this same question three times. I thought to give him some positive angle.

Comment: I guess. But it's all just conjectural. I don't think that it helps.

Comment: @MarkMoralesII Then what can be the counter arguments? That that doesn't happen?

Comment: That it's unlikely to happen. That out of all the possibilities regarding what will happen to us after we die, there's no logical or empirical reason for us to specifically favor this one and worry ourselves over it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134099/discussion-between-felicia-and-mark-morales-ii).

Answer (score 0):

> "What if a demon crept after thee into thy loneliest loneliness some
> day or night, and said to thee: "This life, as thou livest it at
> present, and hast lived it, thou must live it once more, and also
> innumerable times; and there will be nothing new in it, but every pain
> and every joy and every thought and every sigh, and all the
> unspeakably small and great in thy life must come to thee again, and
> all in the same series and sequence—and similarly this spider and this
> moonlight among the trees, and similarly this moment, and I myself.
> The eternal sand-glass of existence will ever be turned once more, and
> thou with it, thou speck of dust!"—Wouldst thou not throw thyself down
> and gnash thy teeth, and curse the demon that so spake? Or hast thou
> once experienced a tremendous moment in which thou wouldst answer him:
> "Thou art a God, and never did I hear anything so divine!" If that
> thought acquired power over thee as thou art, it would transform thee,
> and perhaps crush thee; the question with regard to all and
> everything: "Dost thou want this once more, and also for innumerable
> times?" would lie as the heaviest burden upon thy activity! Or, how
> wouldst thou have to become favourably inclined to thyself and to
> life, so as to long for nothing more ardently than for this last
> eternal sanctioning and sealing?" *-Nietzsche,in The Gay Science*

I regard what Nietzsche as doing here as offering a gedankenexperiment, a thought-experiment on what a maximal affirmation of life would be, and dispensing with regret.

The [Law of Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_identity) would say, either the re-run is *exactly* the same, and you have no memory of it, and would just make every choice the same, or there is some carry-over some memory or change, and you are a different person.  [Teletransportation Paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teletransportation_paradox) are an established kind of thought-experiment that can help with this. We can look at how an exact copy of you, would be very similar, but increasingly begin to diverge and differentiate. A little like a genetically identical twin, great similarity, but different.

In Buddhist thought there are many descriptions of the kind of endless cycling of lives we are. For instance the exercise to cultivate compassion, of recognising all beings have been your mother and father in past lives. I would argue that if there is some small change or variation between recurrences, those will accumulate, even from somehow exactly the same initial conditions (though, in a non-solipsist picture surely everyone else would have the chance to change a little with each recurrence too), and different 'versions of you're will diverge. So, the better picture becomes the Buddhist one than Nierzsche's trapped replay through the same circumstances. More on this here: [Are there specifically Buddhist arguments against the eternal return of the same?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/55064/are-there-specifically-buddhist-arguments-against-the-eternal-return-of-the-same/57608#57608) A modern picturing of rebirth is the Kurzgesacht video [The Egg](https://youtu.be/h6fcK_fRYaI).

There have been [various explorations](https://www.theguardian.com/books/2020/jun/03/top-10-four-dimensional-novels-mark-blacklock-hinton) of what could happen with some freedom to move in time, instead of always moving in one direction. The key thing if this were to apply to humans, would be accounting for what passes from one cycle to another, and it has to account for what we actually experience.

One way to imagine it might be that something from one recurrence, can only change the initial conditions of another, say the genes linked to disposition. In a very real sense if there is a change, the changed is no longer 'you'. But by the same reasoning, we are not completely the same person from day to day. We need to reflect on and consider challenges to our intuitions about identity, and there are tools and thought-experiments like the Ship of Theseus, or Buddhist questions like 'What is your [original face](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Original_face) from before you were born?'. Only with a picture or definition of identity and continuity, can you explore what recurrence might mean.

Comment: Nietzsche isn't above making up his own myths ... the wonder is that people fall for it!